# Mongodb - fetching subdocument in Array

Tags: database, mongodb

My document has the following structure:

```
{ 
"exp" : "2020-01-27", 
"session" : [
    {
        "parameters" : {
            "run" : "2020-01-27-23-01-32_experiment"
        }, 
        "session" : "2eb2e35a-69ea-11ea-b7b6-005056b146e8", 
        "stage" : "intro", 
        "is_finished" : false, 
        "last_modified" : "2020-03-19 15:01:51"
    }, 
    {
        "parameters" : {
            "run" : "2020-01-27-23-01-32_experiment"
        }, 
        "session" : "32edb74c-69ea-11ea-b7b6-005056b146e8", 
        "stage" : "experiment", 
        "is_finished" : true, 
        "last_modified" : "2020-03-19 15:02:22"
    }, 
    {
        "session" : "ffe003e2-69ed-11ea-b7b6-005056b146e8", 
        "parameters" : {
            "run" : "2020-01-27-23-01-32_experiment"
        }, 
        "stage" : "intro", 
        "is_finished" : true, 
        "last_modified" : "2020-03-19 15:29:19"
    }
  ]
}
```

I like to receive all sub documents where is_finished = true. I tried:

```
db.getCollection.sess.find(
    { 
        "session.is_finished" : true
    }, 
    { 
        "session.$.session" : 1
    }
);
```

But I just receive the first element that equals the criteria and not both sub documents.

How can I get all sub documents where is_finished = true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of aggregation:

```
db.aggregate([{$unwind: '$session'},
              {$match: {'session.is_finished': true}])
```